# Sorting vector of x/y coordinates

Tags: sorting, rust

I have a vector of `(u32, u32)` tuples which represent coordinates on a 10 x 10 grid. The coordinates are unsorted. Because the standard `sort` function also didn't yield the result I wanted, I wrote a sort function like this for them:

```
vec.sort_by(|a, b| {
    if a.0 > b.0 { return Ordering::Greater; }
    if a.0 < b.0 { return Ordering::Less; }

    if a.1 > b.1 { return Ordering::Greater; }
    if a.1 < b.1 { return Ordering::Less; }

    return Ordering::Equal;
});
```

The resulting grid for my custom function looks like this:

```
(0/0)   (0/1)   (0/2)   (0/3)   (0/4)   (0/5)   (0/6)   (0/7)   (0/8)   (0/9)
(1/0)   (1/1)   (1/2)   (1/3)   (1/4)   (1/5)   (1/6)   (1/7)   (1/8)   (1/9)
(2/0)   (2/1)   (2/2)   (2/3)   (2/4)   (2/5)   (2/6)   (2/7)   (2/8)   (2/9)
...
(9/0)   (9/1)   (9/2)   (9/3)   (9/4)   (9/5)   (9/6)   (9/7)   (9/8)   (9/9)
```

This is not what I want, because the lower left should start with `(0/0)` as I would expect on a mathematical coordinates grid.

I probably can manage to add more cases to the sort algorithm, but is there an easier way to do what I want besides writing a big `if .. return Ordering ...;` block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't show how you are populating or printing your tuples, so this is a guess. Flip around and/or negate parts of your coordinates. I'd also recommend using `sort_by_key` as it's easier, as well as just reusing the existing comparison of tuples:

```
fn main() {
    let mut points = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 1)];
    points.sort_by_key(|&(x, y)| (!y, x));
    println!("{:?}", points);
}
```

Adding an extra newline in the output:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 1),
 (0, 0), (1, 0)]
```

Originally, this answer suggested negating the value (`(-y, x)`). However, as [pointed out by Francis Gagné](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274792/sorting-vector-of-x-y-coordinates#comment67810637_40275230), this fails for unsigned integers or signed integers when the value is the minimum value. Negating the bits happens to work fine, but is a bit too "clever".

Nowadays, I would use [`Ordering::reverse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/enum.Ordering.html#method.reverse) and [`Ordering::then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/enum.Ordering.html#method.then) for the clarity:

```
fn main() {
    let mut points = [(0u8, 0u8), (1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 1)];
    points.sort_by(|&(x0, y0), &(x1, y1)| y0.cmp(&y1).reverse().then(x0.cmp(&x1)));
    println!("{:?}", points);
}
```

```
[(0, 1), (1, 1),
 (0, 0), (1, 0)]
```

Comment: Thank you, I must have overlooked `sort_by_key`.

Comment: I think `!y` would be a better choice than `-y` (which is basically equivalent to `!y + 1`). For signed integers, `-y` would sort `iN::MIN` incorrectly. For unsigned integers, `-y` is a compile time error (if it weren't, then 0 would be sorted incorrectly).