# Reverse specific key when sorting with multiple keys

Tags: sorting, rust

When sorting with multiple keys, how can I reverse the order of an individual key? For example:

```
vec.sort_by_key(|k| (foo(k).reverse(), bar(k)));
```

Comment: By multiple keys, do you mean multiple sorting criteria (each being of descending priority)?

Comment: @E_net4 Yes. If the tuple was (x, y), then sort with x and break ties with y. Except in this case I want descending order for x.

Comment: Your example works just fine for the appropriate implementations of `foo`, `reverse`, and `bar`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`sort_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_by) paired with [`Ordering::reverse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/enum.Ordering.html#method.reverse) instead of `sort_by_key`.

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo(&'static str, u8);

impl Foo {
    fn name(&self) -> &str { self.0 }
    fn len(&self) -> u8 { self.1 }
}

fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![Foo("alpha", 1), Foo("beta", 2), Foo("beta", 1)];

    vec.sort_by(|a, b| {
        match a.name().cmp(b.name()).reverse() {
            Ordering::Equal => a.len().cmp(&b.len()),
            other => other,
        }
    });

    println!("{:?}", vec);
}
```

This sorts in reverse alphabetical order, then ties are sorted in ascending numerical order:

```
[Foo("beta", 1), Foo("beta", 2), Foo("alpha", 1)]
```

Since Rust 1.17 (via [RFC 1677](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1677)), you can write it like this:

```
vec.sort_by(|a, b| {
    a.name().cmp(b.name()).reverse()
        .then(a.len().cmp(&b.len()))
});
```

If you have something that can naturally be negated / inverted, you can [simply negate the key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40274792/155423).

Comment: Thanks. So `sort_by` is more powerful than `sort_by_key`: `sort_by` can do everything that `sort_by_key` can do, but `sort_by_key` cannot do everything `sort_by` can do. What's the advantage of using `sort_by_key`?

Comment: @HiDefender it's way simpler for extremely common cases. It may even work for your case, as I linked to in the other question.

Comment: Once again, thank you. Two more questions: 1. You pass `&b.len()` in the second compare. Why does cmp() not support passing ownership, only borrowing? 2. Is it necessary for your struct to have `[derive(Debug)]`? Couldn't it be sorted without that?

Comment: @HiDefender the comparison operator doesn't need ownership of the right-hand member, so it just borrows. It doesn't depend on whether it's cheaper to move or pass a reference (even though it might sound like it is from a C++ programmer's perspective). Also, you wouldn't need `#[derive(Debug)]` but it's recommended that all types implement this trait.

Answer (score 10):

Since Rust 1.19, the [`std::cmp::Reverse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/struct.Reverse.html) struct wraps a value and implements `PartialOrd` and `Ord` by calling `partial_cmp` and `cmp` with swapped arguments in order to return the reversed order. Just wrap the key to sort in descending order:

```
vec.sort_by_key(|k| (Reverse(foo(k)), bar(k)));
```

Before Rust 1.19, you can use the [`revord`](https://crates.io/crates/revord) crate ([documentation](https://docs.rs/revord/)) which provides the struct `RevOrd` which provides the same benefit::

```
vec.sort_by_key(|k| (RevOrd(foo(k)), bar(k)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a similar approach to the problem: create a function for chaining multiple orderings:

```
/// chain two orderings: the first one gets more priority
fn chain_ordering(o1: Ordering, o2: Ordering) -> Ordering {
    match o1 {
        Ordering::Equal => o2,
        _ => o1,
    }
}
```

Then use `sort_by`, possibly with pattern matching, to produce the ordering of each key:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct HeroSkill(&'static str, &'static str);

fn main() {
    // a vector of hero names and super powers
    let mut v = vec![
        HeroSkill("Bob", "X"),
        HeroSkill("Bob", "Y"),
        HeroSkill("Alice", "X")
    ];

    // sort by name, then by super power, where Y is more powerful than X
    v.sort_by(|&HeroSkill(name1, power1), &HeroSkill(name2, power2)| {
        chain_ordering(name1.cmp(name2), power1.cmp(power2).reverse())
    });

    assert_eq!(v, vec![
        HeroSkill("Alice", "X"),
        HeroSkill("Bob", "Y"),
        HeroSkill("Bob", "X")
    ]);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=33ea6a3a3ebedc49234be16a85df3399&version=stable&backtrace=0)