# How (if possible) to sort a BTreeMap by value in Rust?

Tags: sorting, rust, word-frequency

I am following a course on Software Security for which one of the assignments is to write some basic programs in Rust. For one of these assignments I need to analyze a text-file and generate several statistics. One of these is a generated list of the ten most used words in the text.

I have written [this program](http://pastebin.com/ffdQ7Zsr) that performs all tasks in the assignment  except for the word frequency statistic mentioned above, the program compiles and executes the way I expect:

```
extern crate regex;

use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::path::Path;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    // Create a path to the desired file
    let path = Path::new("text.txt");
    let display = path.display();

    let file = match File::open(&path) {
        Err(why) => panic!("couldn't open {}: {}", display,
                           why.description()),
        Ok(file) => file,
    };

    let mut wordcount = 0;
    let mut averagesize = 0;
    let mut wordsize = BTreeMap::new();
    let mut words = BTreeMap::new();

    for line in (BufReader::new(file)).lines() {
        let re = Regex::new(r"([A-Za-z]+[-_]*[A-Za-z]+)+").unwrap();
        for cap in re.captures_iter(&line.unwrap()) {
            let word = cap.at(1).unwrap_or("");
            let lower = word.to_lowercase();
            let s = lower.len();

            wordcount += 1;
            averagesize += s;

            *words.entry(lower).or_insert(0) += 1;
            *wordsize.entry(s).or_insert(0) += 1;
        }
    }

    averagesize = averagesize / wordcount;

    println!("This file contains {} words with an average of {} letters per word.", wordcount, averagesize);

    println!("\nThe number of times a word of a certain length was found.");

    for (size, count) in wordsize.iter() {
        println!("There are {} words of size {}.", count, size);
    }

    println!("\nThe ten most used words.");

    let mut popwords = BTreeMap::new();
    for (word, count) in words.iter() {
        if !popwords.contains_key(count) {
            popwords.insert(count, "");
        }

        let newstring = format!("{} {}", popwords.get(count), word);
        let mut e = popwords.get_mut(count);
    }

    let mut i = 0;
    for (count, words) in popwords.iter() {
        i += 1;
        if i > 10 {
            break;
        }
        println!("{} times: {}", count, words);
    }
}
```

I have a `BTreeMap` (that I chose with [these](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/) instructions), `words`, that stores each word as key and its associated frequency in the text as value. This functionality works as I expect, but there I am stuck. I have been trying to find ways to sort the `BTreemap` by value or find another data structure in Rust that is natively sorted by value.

I am looking for the correct way to achieve this data structure (a list of words with their frequency, sorted by frequency) in Rust. Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you need it to be indexed by word *and* sorted by value, that sounds like two data structures (possibly wrapped together).  I think I would probably accumulate the counts in a `BTreeMap` or `HashMap`, and then turn that into a `Vec` at the end.

Comment: Out of interest, what/where is the course?

Comment: @ChrisEmerson it's part of the 4TU Master Cyber Security programme in the Netherlands, a joint programme by the University of Twente and Delft University, where I'm attending via the first university.

Comment: Just to point out, a `BTreeMap` is sorted **by key**; that's how it works. See the requirement for `Ord` for `K`. If you could sort by value, the properties of the map would no longer hold, and it couldn't *be* a map.

Comment: If you are interested in improving your code, you may want to ask a question [over on Code Review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you only need to analyze a static dataset, the easiest way is to just convert your `BTreeMap` into a `Vec<T>` in the end and sort the latter ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5561b3fb979221008088ceee6cdcdce5&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
use std::iter::FromIterator;

let mut v = Vec::from_iter(map);
v.sort_by(|&(_, a), &(_, b)| b.cmp(&a));
```

The vector contains the `(key, value)` pairs as tuple. To sort the vector, we have to use `sort_by()` or `sort_by_key()`. To sort the vector in decreasing order, I used `b.cmp(&a)` (as opposed to `a.cmp(&b)`, which would be the natural order). But there are [other possibilities to reverse the order of a sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369255/reverse-specific-key-when-sorting-with-multiple-keys).

---

However, if you really need some data structure such that you have a streaming calculation, it's getting more complicated. There are many possibilities in that case, but I guess using some kind of priority queue could work out.

Comment: This seems to be the solution to my problem. I never realized I could use a vector in this way. I'll try it right away.

Comment: You may want to use [the revord crate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40369255/155423) instead of negating - `-MIN_INT` is not representable.

Comment: @Shepmaster I worked around that problem by explicitly declaring the count as a signed integer with `wordlenghts.insert(word.to_lowercase(), word.chars().count() as i64);`. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: @Jonathan that... makes it worse. By moving to a **signed** integer, you introduce the possibility of having `MIN_INT` to start with. An unsigned number, of course, cannot be negated, requiring the reverse ordering.

Comment: This suggestion resolved my problem completely, after ironing out the issue @Shepmaster also pointed out. The working code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/FMkkcJsm).

Comment: @Shepmaster I see. I'll update my program accordingly. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: @Shepmaster I fixed the ordering stuff. Thanks for the comment!