# How can I do a multiple nested sort using partial_cmp?

Tags: sorting, rust

I have the following code which is trying to sort a table by 2 criteria

```
    fn order_test() {
    let sort_column_indices = [0, 1];
    let table_1 = vec![
        [1., 44200.0],
        [2.0, 44200.0],
        [2.0, 44259.0],
        [3.0, 44200.0],
        [3.0, 44259.0],
        [4.0, 44312.0],
        [5.0, 44231.0],
        [5.0, 44259.0],
        [5.0, 44381.0],
        [1.0, 44231.0],
        [3.0, 44231.0],
        [2.0, 44231.0],
        [5.0, 44200.0],
    ];
    // Retrieve the rows and assign a row index
    let mut l_table_idx_v = table_1
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .map(move |(idx, row)| {
            (
                idx,
                sort_column_indices
                    .iter()
                    .map(|sci| row[*sci].to_owned())
                    .collect::<Vec<_>>(),
            )
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    // Sort - this is wrong
    l_table_idx_v.sort_by(|a, b| {
        let lhs = &a.1;
        let rhs = &b.1;
        let mut ordering = None;
        let sz = lhs.len() - 1;
        for i in 0..lhs.len() {
            ordering = Some(
                ((&lhs[sz - i]).partial_cmp(&rhs[sz - i]))
                    .unwrap()
                    .reverse(),
            );
        }
        ordering.unwrap()
    });
    // Reverse the indices output
    l_table_idx_v.reverse();

    let mut results = Vec::new();
    for (j, _) in l_table_idx_v {
        let row = table_1[j];
        row.iter().for_each(|&v| {
            results.push(v);
        })
    }
    dbg!(results);
}
```

This results in

```
results = [
    1.0,    44200.0,
    1.0,    44231.0,
    2.0,    44200.0,
    2.0,    44259.0,
    2.0,    44231.0,
    3.0,    44200.0,
    3.0,    44259.0,
    3.0,    44231.0,
    4.0,    44312.0,
    5.0,    44231.0,
    5.0,    44259.0,
    5.0,    44381.0,
    5.0,    44200.0,
]
```

First column sorted ok, but second one is not.

Expected result for 2.0

```
2.0,    44200.0,
2.0,    44231.0,
2.0,    44259.0,
```

I want to be able to have more than 2 criteria eventually so I've written the partial_cmp part as a loop but it's not quite right.

Minimum example is using ndarray

**EDIT**

[Reverse specific key when sorting with multiple keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369255/reverse-specific-key-when-sorting-with-multiple-keys) is close, but doesn't suggest how to generalise to more than 2 criteria.

Rewrote example with no dependency on non-standard libs. Can be used in playground

Appreciate any help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse specific key when sorting with multiple keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369255/reverse-specific-key-when-sorting-with-multiple-keys)

Comment: No - it doesn't scale past 2 criteria, or at least it's not obvious to me

Comment: adapt it the same logic apply. you already have a `let sort_column_indices = [0, 1];` that look like the right path to me

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Stargateur, the idea clicked finally. This is how it can be extended to multiple sorts

The change to the sort_by is

```
        l_table_idx_v.sort_by(|a, b| {
            let lhs = &a.1;
            let rhs = &b.1;
            // First check
            let mut ordering = lhs[0].partial_cmp(&rhs[0]).unwrap();
            // Only apply subsequent checks if the first one is equal
            for i in 1..lhs.len() {
                if ordering == std::cmp::Ordering::Equal {
                    ordering = lhs[i].partial_cmp(&rhs[i]).unwrap();
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            ordering
        });
```